# How to change axis labels when using YellowBrick's KElbowVisualizer?

Tags: python, plot, yellowbrick

I am using the following code to create a silhouette coefficient plot with KElbowVisualizer:

```
# Import the KElbowVisualizer method 

# Instantiate a scikit-learn K-Means model
model = KMeans(random_state=0)

# Instantiate the KElbowVisualizer with the number of clusters and the metric 
titleKElbow = "title"

visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(2,7), metric='silhouette', timings=False,title = titleKElbow)

# Fit the data and visualize
visualizer.fit(df[['a','b','c']])    
visualizer.poof()
```

In the resulting plot the x axis label is 'k'. How can I change the axis labels on the resulting plot? I have tried the [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/yellowbrick-tr/downloads/pdf/latest/), but as far as I know it only shows how to add axis labels in a plt style plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the `ax` property of the visualizer and use the `set_xlabel` method on it directly:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer


model = KMeans(random_state=0)
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(
    model, 
    k=(2,7), 
    metric="silhouette", 
    timings=False,
    title="custom title"
)

visualizer.fit(df[["a", "b", "c"]])
visualizer.ax.set_xlabel("custom x label")
plt.show()
```

Thanks for checking out Yellowbrick!

Comment: Thank you! Just want to point out that the "custom title" does not show in this case, it can be added with plt.title()